# What protocol does VS Code Remote use?

Tags: vscode-remote

As far as I can tell there's no docs on the protocol that the client and server communicate with. The FAQ specifies that it communicates over an SSH tunnel, but what is the protocol that is sent between client and server?

Is it JSON/Protobuf/XML/etc.? What do the structure of the messages look like? Is there documentation but I just haven't been able to find it?

Comment: I found this documentation. Maybe can help.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh